# Exclude the category of the current post

Tags: categories

I have a simple site that shows one random post when you reach it. This post then has a link below it that, when clicked, will pull in another random post to that homepage,  excluding all posts from the category that the current post is in.

Eg. A post from category 'Bikes' is shown. Below it is a link that needs to replace that post with another random post from all the categories excluding the posts in 'Bikes'

I am finding it easy to find code for excluding a set category but i can't find a way to read what post category is shown on the page and exclude only that.

I would greatly appreciate any advice.

WordPress
Version 3.1

Answer (score 1):

`wp_get_post_categories()` [(Codex reference)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories) is used to get the categories for a post

Comment: I'm not trying to get the categories for a post, I'm trying to get all the posts in a category but exclude the current post

Comment: @user983248 then you should ask a separate question.

Comment: Hi sorry, but I had two browsers windows and I got confused, This is not even my question. I was trying to reply to a comment on a question of my own. Sorry anu :)